# Grails: Handle post requests with unkown numbers of key value-pairs

Tags: grails, http-post

I am writing a controller capable of handeling different types of post requests.

As a result I would like to be able to get the number of key value pairs in the request, then retrive them as some form of object (a list or some kind of iterator) so that I can loop through them retrieve their key and values and handle them appropriately.

Something like as follows:

```
def sz = request.size  // may or may not be necessary, but would still like to know how
def keyValPairs = request.listOfPosts
for (def keyVal : keyValPairs) {
    def key = keyVal.getKey();
    def val = keyVal.getVal();
    doSomething(key, val);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to mention here. First of all, it all depends on the encoding of the POST data. For example, if you send the data in JSON format, converting it to a map is different than if you send it as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (that is the case if you send the data from a HTML form).

If the latter is true, the only thing you need to do is to use `getParameterMap()` from plain old [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29). Grails only overrides this method to provide a data structure that plays nicely with routing, namely [GrailsParameterMap](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I should have been more specific about what type of data I am trying to retrieve. In fact I am trying to retrieve Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded (HTML form-like data sent via post or key-value pairs like I like to call it). I will add my final code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So an example solution would be:

```
def controllerFunction() {

    def enu = request.getParameterMap();
    String msg = "";

    for (def obj : enu) {
        msg += "\n<br/> Object key: " + obj.key;
        msg += "\n<br/> Object value: " + obj.value[0]; // [0] seems to remove some problematic square brackets that wrap around the value
        msg += "\n<br/> ";                  
    }

    render rtn; 
}
```